Ros2 Slam_Toolbox Issues with saved map corruption when in localization mode
I am running slam_toolbox along with the nav2 stack on ROS2 Jazzy. Currently, when I boot up my nodes with slam_toolbox in the localization mode, everything loads fine, until the first "localization" attempt is made, after which the map becomes corrupted, compared to the saved map data. Both pictured below.
This issue occurs not only when rviz is open and the pose estimate tool is used, but also if the robot is driven from the dock. This only occurs on the first pass, if the robot successfully localizes initially the map will be fine for the duration of that run. Also, the map file on disk is not affected, only what is loaded with the nodes.
 
This are the relevant logs, if that would help.

    [rviz2-29] [INFO] [1722980497.792477172] [rviz2]: Setting estimate pose: Frame:map, Position(-1.33064, -0.800631, 0), Orientation(0, 0, -0.973379, 0.229201) = Angle: -2.67908
    [localization_slam_toolbox_node-17] [INFO] [1722980497.796829642] [slam_toolbox]: LocalizePoseCallback: Localizing to: (-1.33 -0.80), theta=-2.68
    [localization_slam_toolbox_node-17] W20240806 16:41:38.053278 79953 preprocessor.cc:67] Specified options.num_threads: 50 exceeds maximum available from the threading model Ceres was compiled with: 8.  Bounding to maximum number available.
    [rviz2-29] [INFO] [1722980498.154512129] [rviz2]: Trying to create a map of size 337 x 396 using 1 swatches
    [planner_server-21] [INFO] [1722980498.977380180] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 337 X 396 at 0.050000 m/pix
    [rviz2-29] [INFO] [1722980499.039582914] [rviz2]: Trying to create a map of size 337 x 396 using 1 swatches


